# How to execute selenium test script in android, iOS, ipad using saucelabs

Tags: android, ios, ipad, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I am able to run my script in three browser using saucelabs, but I need to run it in mobile devices as well as ipad. Can some one help me how can I add desiredCapabilities? My code is as follows:

```
public static Object[][] sauceBrowserDataProvider(Method testMethod) {
    return new Object[][]{
            //new Object[]{"internet explorer", "11", "Windows 8.1"},
            //new Object[]{"firefox", "44", "Windows 7"},
            new Object[]{"browser", "44", "Android"},
            new Object[]{"chrome", "51","Windows 7"},
            new Object[]{"firefox", "44","iOS"}
    };
}

private WebDriver createDriver(String browser, String version, String os) throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, browser);
    if (version != null) {
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, version);
    }
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, os);
    capabilities.setCapability("name", "Sauce Sample Test");
    webDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://" + authentication.getUsername() + ":" + authentication.getAccessKey() + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
            capabilities));
    sessionId.set(((RemoteWebDriver) getWebDriver()).getSessionId().toString());
    return webDriver.get();
}

@Test(dataProvider = "hardCodedBrowsers")
public void webDriver(String browser, String version, String os) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = createDriver(browser, version, os);
}
```

Using this code I am able to run in three browsers but not able to run mobile devices. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried something like this:

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.deviceName, "Google Nexus 7 HD Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.browserName, "Safari");
```

I have tried something similar with BrowserStack and it works.

Please let me know.

Comment: Hi what do you mean by not working? Do you get an error message? Were you able t fix it?

Answer (score 0):

private WebDriver createDriver() throws MalformedURLException {

```
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

   /*capabilities.setCapability("platformName", platformName);
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
   //capabilities.setCapability("app", this.appURI);
   capabilities.setCapability("browserName", browserName);
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", deviceOrientation);
   capabilities.setCapability("appiumVersion", appiumVersion);*/

    caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.5.3");
    caps.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone 6s Simulator");
    caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion","9.1");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
```

}

I added this code to my script and its working fine now.Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use QMetry Automation Framework where you can provide [configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/creating_configuration_file.html) out side code.

You need use remote driver and to set following properties to point your execution on sauce labs.

```
remote.server=http://username:AccessKey@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
remote.port=80
```

Provide appropriate driver capabilities. Refer [setting driver capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html).

Note: Make sure you are providing remote driver in driver name. for example

```
driver.name=firefoxRemoteDriver
```